# Using sensors, how can I control the movement of each bone individually?

Tags: python, 3d-view, bones, game-engine

I fixed the sensor on the human body, obtained the posture data of the human body, and uploaded it to Blender for display.  The problem is, I found that when I move the sensor of the father bone, the display in blender is like this:
[image]
In fact, the child sensor does not move, I think this bone should remain in its original state on blender:

[image](this is a gif)

I think the correct display should be like this:
[image]
How to change the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want child bone to do not rotate with parent, you can disable inherit rotation in bone settings:

[image]

Comment: yes, it can solve my problem! thank you